# limits of 2 lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Compute the following limits, with justification, where the integrals denote Lebesgue integrals:

1. $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{m\sin (y/m)}{y(1+y^2)} dy$.
2. $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{1+my^2}{(1+y^2)^m}dy.$

For 1), I think it's useful to use the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{\sin c}{4!} x^4,$ where $c\in (0,x)$. Fix $m\ge 1$. Applying the above expansion to $\sin(y/m),$ we get $\frac{y}m - \frac{(y/m)^3}{3!} + \frac{(y/m)^4}{4!}\ge \sin(y/m) \ge \frac{y}m - \frac{y^3}{3! m^3} - \frac{(y/m)^4}{4!}$. Hence letting $g_m(y) = \frac{y}m - \frac{y^3}{3! m^3}, f_m(y) =  \dfrac{m\sin (y/m)}{y(1+y^2)}$, we have that for all $y\ge 0,$ $h_m^-(y) := \dfrac{1-y^2/(6m^2) - y^3/(24m^3)}{1+y^2}= \dfrac{m(g_m(y) - \frac{1}{24}(y/m)^4)}{y(1+y^2)} \leq f_m(y)\leq \dfrac{m(\frac{y}m - \frac{y^3}{3! m^3} + \frac{1}{24}(y/m)^4)}{y(1+y^2)} =: h_m^{-}(y).$

Note that both $h_m^-(y)$ and $h_m^+(y)$ converge pointwise to $\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ as $m\to \infty$, which implies by the Squeeze theorem that $\dfrac{m \sin(y/m)}{y(1+y^2)}$ converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ as $m\to\infty$. Also, $|\dfrac{m\sin(y/m)}{y(1+y^2)}|\leq |\dfrac{m(\frac{y}m - \frac{y^3}{3! m^3} + \frac{1}{24}(y/m)^4)}{y(1+y^2)}|$. But I need to upper bound $f_m(y)$ by an integrable function (a function $g$ so that $\int_0^\infty |g| dy < \infty$) to use the Dominated convergence theorem.

For the second limit, for any $y > 0, $ one has L'Hopital's rule that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \dfrac{1+my^2}{(1+y^2)^m} = \lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \dfrac{my^2}{(1+y^2)^m} = 0.$ The issue is that to apply the Dominated convergence theorem, I need to find an upper bound for the integrand that's integrable.

Comment: The first integral has a closed form. $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{m\sin (y/m)}{y(1+y^2)} dy=\frac{m}{2}\Im\int_0^{-\infty} \frac{e^{iy/m}}{y(1+y^2)} dy$. Closing the contour by a big half-circle in the complex upper half-plane (counter-clockwise) and adding a small arch around $y=0$ (clockwise), given that there is one pole inside the contour (at $y=i$)
$$I=\frac{m}{2}\Im\Big(\pi i Res_{y=o}\frac{e^{iy/m}}{y(1+y^2)}+2\pi i Res_{y=i}\frac{e^{iy/m}}{y(1+y^2)}\Big)=\frac{m}{2}\Im\Big(\pi i -\pi i e^{-1/m}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{\pi m}{2}\big(1-e^{-1/m}\big)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav. We do not need contour integration. We even have the antiderivative.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, you are right: there are many ways to the goal. CI, in my opinion, can provide a shortcut to an answer in many cases - if the task has an appropriate symmetry. I guessed this was the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) use the fact that $|\sin t| \leq t$ for all $t >0$ so a dominating function is $\frac 1 {1+y^{2}}$.

For 2) use the fact that $(1+y^{2})^{m} \geq 1+my^{2}$ so a dominating function is the constant function $1$.

[The function $(1+x)^{m}-1-mx$ vanishes when $x=0$ and its dervative is $m[(1+x)^{m-1}-1]$ which is non-negative for $m >1, x \geq 0$. Hence, $(1+x)^{m}-1-mx\geq 0$].

Comment: Or you could just use the Binomial theorem to show a stronger result since $m$ is an integer.

Comment: @FredJefferson Yes,  I didn't realize that your $m$ was an integer. The result is true even if you take limit as $m \to \infty$ through real values.